# Python Tkinter Flashing Standard Window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building an Interface with TKinter and I have the problem, that whenever create a new window the standardized tkinter window of 200x200 pixel with nothing in it flashes up for a fraction of a second and AFTER that all my modifications (widgets ect.) are made. This happens before AND after calling the mainloop.

- The Main-Interface is created.
- Mainloop stats
- Flashing window
- Main-Interface appears

Also after Mainloop was called this happens with newly created windows.

- Main-Interface appears--> Push a button, that creates a new window
- Flashing window
- new window appears

Sadly I cannot give you a sample code... If I try to do a minimal example, this doesn't happen. Maybe the standard window is created, but it is changed so fast, that it doesn't appear on screen. I don't even know what to look up in this case... searching "tkinter flashing window" yields nothing.

**EDIT:** I found the source of the problem. It seems to be caused by `wm_iconbitmap`, `FigureCanvasTkAgg` and `tkinter.Toplevel`. If you remove the the icon out of the code, it works fine, no flashing. But if I use it together with one of the other, the window flashes when created. Try it out with the code below. You have to put the icon in the working directory of course.

Here is a code sample and [the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/edmh1tkvku6g46z/icon.ico) to the icon I am using, but I suppose any icon will do.

```
# coding=utf-8
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk
import os

class INTERFACE(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.EXIT)
        self.root.wm_iconbitmap( os.path.abspath("icon.ico"))  #<---- !!!!!!
        self.root.geometry("1024x768")
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.testfigure(), master=self.root) #<---- !!!!!!
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.E+tk.S)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    def testfigure(self):
        x=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi,100)
        y=np.sin(x)
        fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
        sub = fig.add_subplot(111)
        sub.plot(x,y)
        return fig

    def EXIT(self):
        Top = tk.Toplevel(master=self.root)
        Top.wm_iconbitmap( os.path.abspath("icon.ico"))  #<---- !!!!!!
        Top.transient(self.root)
        Top.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        Top.title("Exit")

        tk.Message(Top,text="Do you really want to quit?", justify=tk.CENTER, width=300).grid(row=0,columnspan=3)
        tk.Button(Top,text="YES",command=self.root.destroy).grid(row=1,column=0)
        tk.Button(Top,text="No",command=self.root.destroy).grid(row=1,column=1)
        tk.Button(Top,text="Maybe",command=self.root.destroy).grid(row=1,column=2)
    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    INTERFACE().start()
```

Comment: So actually you problem is not with tkinter, since as you said, if you create a minimal code (a dummy version) it is working as you wished. This leads us to the point -> your other part of the code has the bug! So 1) show us your code or 2) start to debug it from a state where it is working (the dummy version) and add the features you want step-by-step and catch the problem..

Comment: I added a sample code and I found the trouble makers. Would you please have a look at it again?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I've experienced a similar situation and have found a solution.

In my case, I've isolated the issue to the use of `iconbitmap`. I've managed to solve it by calling `iconbitmap` with the `after` method just before calling `root.mainloop()`.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
    w.pack()

    root.geometry('300x300+500+500')
    root.after(50, root.iconbitmap('icon.ico'))
    root.mainloop()
```

This method has worked on Toplevel() windows with icons as well.

Tested on Win 8.1 with Python 3.5.0.

Edit: Upon further inspection I've noticed that the behavior changes relative to `root.geometry`'s presence as well. My initial example didn't have it and I only noticed after a few tries that it still had the same issue. The time delay in the `after` method doesn't seem to change anything.

Moving `root.geometry` below the `after` method yields the same issue for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, somewhere in your initialization code you're calling `update` or `update_idletasks`, which causes the current state of the GUI to be drawn on the screen.

Another possible source of the problem is if you're creating multiple instances of `Tk` rather than `Toplevel`.

Without seeing your code, though, all we can do is guess.

Your best route to solving this problem is to create a small example that has the same behavior. Not because we need it to help you, but because the effort you put into recreating the bug will likely teach you what is causing the bug.

Comment: I added a sample code and I found the trouble makers. Would you please have a look at it again?

Answer (score 0):

This should work but it requires win32gui

```
import win32gui

def FlashMyWindow(title):
    ID = win32gui.FindWindow(None, title)
    win32gui.FlashWindow(ID,True)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to write any extra code just do this and this works fine for example

```
# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Window")
window.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
window_width = 520
window_height = 500
```

so if I do something like this above code given then there will be screen flickering or flash screen. To solve this issue just don't declare the iconbitmap while creating the window, you can add it when declaring the main event like this

```
# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Window")
window_width = 520
window_height = 500

/* ------some codes-------*/

#create the main event
window.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
window.mainloop()
```

This may solve your problem.

I hope it helps